# Mouse events fire on all overlapping elements

Tags: javascript, events, mouseevent, event-listener, overlapping

I have overlapping div elements. 
When the any element is moused over, I want the event on it to fire. No matter if it's on top or below. If there are three overlapping, they should all fire.

So console should log "one" "two" "three" when moused over over all of them.
but right now it's just logging whatever is on top.

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/csepf7nk/6/

```
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

divs.forEach(div => div.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.classList.value);
}));
```

Is it possible to modify the event listener in some way?
or to modify the element?

I saw this example, but it's going to effect performance hard on my project.
http://jsfiddle.net/michaschwab/w0wufbtn/6/
I'm looking for something way more simple since I have a huge amount of overlapping elements.

Comment: `e.target.classList.value` would always be the actual element which triggered the event, so it would be always the same element, so even if you make it work the output would always be `"one" "one" "one"` or whichever element is clicked.

Comment: ok, so would I do that? figuring this out would be a step in the right direction. I can change e.target.classList.value later.